# ScrollViewer Horizontal mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: scroll, windows-runtime

I'm trying to find a way to scroll a horizontal ScrollViewer with the mouse wheel in WimRT. I know it is easy to achieve in WPF, but no such workarounds seem to be working in WinRT. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: depending on what you're trying to accomplish, horizontal scrolling does work with the mouse wheel (for example in a listview). the problem is if you're trying to do both horizontal and vertical, I'd suggest you try using the simulator and touch simulation, which work really great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've done so far you should just be able to set the ScollViewer's style to

```
Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}"
```

Which is defined in `StandardStyles.xaml`